# A special interpolation inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading a paper, but getting stuck in the following inequality. I want to know whether it is correct or not.

$\Omega=(-\infty,\infty)\times [0,1]$ and for any smooth function $u=0$ only on the lower boundary $(-\infty,\infty)\times\{0\}$ then

$$||u||_{4}\leq C||\nabla u||_{2}^{\frac{3}{4}}||\partial_{1} u||_{2}^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Is this true? How to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: This very strongly reminds me of the Ladyzhenskaya inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyzhenskaya%27s_inequality

Comment: @rubikscube09 This is 2D. The indexes are different.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the correction, just threw out a wild guess.

Comment: I think this roughly follows from the 2D Ladyzhenskaya inequality plus the bound $$\|u\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{L^\infty([0,1], L^2((-\infty,\infty)))} \lesssim \|\partial_2 u\|_{L^2} $$ using that $u$ vanishes on the bottom boundary, and that $[0,1]$ is bounded interval, but I haven't worked through the details.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you very much for your comment. But using your idea I could only reach $$||u||_{4}^{2}\leq ||\partial_{2}u||_{2} ||\nabla u||_{2} $$.

Comment: @KiraYamato: you need the Gagliardo-Nirenberg form of Ladyzhenskaya, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First we copy the proof of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality:*

Notice that $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^4(\Omega)$, and so we can assume the functions we are working with have compact support. For convenience I will denote $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in [0,1]$, then by fundamental theorem of calculus

$$ |u(x,y)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\partial_x u(s,y)| ~ds, \qquad |u(x,y)| \leq \int_0^1 |\partial_y u(x,t)| ~dt $$

where the first expression we used decay at infinity for $x$, and the second we used $u(x,0) = 0$.

Thus 
$$ |u(x,y)|^4 \leq 4 \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u(s,y)| |\partial_x u(s,y)| ~ds \right)\cdot\left( \int_0^1 |u(x,t)| |\partial_y u(x,t)| ~dt \right) $$
and hence
$$ \|u\|^4_4 \leq 4 \| u \partial_x u\|_1 \cdot \|u \partial_y u\|_1 \leq 4 \|u\|_2^2 \|\partial_x u\|_2 \|\partial_y u\|_2 $$

*Next we integrate in $y$ to control $\|u\|_2$*:

Since

$$ |u(x,y)|^2 = \int_0^y u(x,t) \partial_y u(x,t) ~dt $$

after integrating in $x$ and applying Fubini we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |u(x,y)|^2 ~dx \leq \int_0^y \|u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \|\partial_y u(\cdot,t) \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} $$

Or that

$$ \|u\|^2_{L^\infty_y L^2_x} \leq \|u\|_{L^\infty_y L^2_x} \|\partial_y u\|_{L^1_y L^2_x} $$

This implies

$$ \|u\|_2 \leq \|u\|^2_{L^\infty_y L^2_x} \leq \|\partial_y u\|_{L^1_y L^2_x} \leq \|\partial_y u\|_{2} $$

*So putting everything together we have*

$$ \|u\|_4^4 \leq 4 \|\partial_y u\|_2^3 \|\partial_x u\|_2^1 $$

which implies the desired claim.